# How to get error to be displayed

Tags: java, exception

```
public void runMenu() {
        int x = 1;
        Scanner Option = new Scanner(System.in);
        int Choice = 0;

        do {
            try {
                System.out.println("Choose Option");
                System.out.println("");
                System.out.println("1: Create Account");
                System.out.println("2: Check Account");
                System.out.println("3: Take Action");
                System.out.println("4: Exit");

                System.out.println("Please choose");
                Choice = Option.nextInt();

                switch (Choice) //used switch statement instead of If else because more effective
                {
                    case 1:
                        CreateAccount();
                        break;   //breaks iteration
                    case 2:
                        selectAccount();
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        break;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Cant do that");
            }
        } while (Choice < 4);
        System.out.println("Bye");
    }
```

The exception handling doesnt work e.g. if I enter say outide the range such as 5 it should say something like "Cant do that". Should I enter a if statement defining the condition if so how can I go about doing that? right now it just prints "Bye" if I enter wrong key.

Comment: Input outside of your range doesn't cause an exception. Exceptions are triggered by an input that causes a problem when processed.This might help you http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_exceptions.htm

Comment: There is no part in your code that tells it to throw an exception if the input is an unexpected value. Maybe use the `default:` case of the switch. (Whether using exceptions here in the first place is correct is debatable)

Comment: The `break` applies to the switch; not the loop.

Comment: What about a incorrect input e.g. if you set an if statement (Choice<4) can it be done then to display user an error and return back to menus?

Comment: "if I enter say outide the range such as 5 it should say something like "Cant do that"" <-- what exactly makes you think that the current code will do that? `.nextInt()` will try and grab any valid integer from the input. 5 is valid...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is due to the fact that your looping while `Choice < 4`.

You should change your loop to `while(true);` and then inside your switch case, create a case 4 which exits the program using `System.exit(0)`

Then include a default which will inform the user that they input an invalid value

```
public void runMenu() {

    int x = 1;
    Scanner Option = new Scanner (System.in);
    int Choice = 0; 

  do{  
    try{



           System.out.println("Choose Option");
             System.out.println("");
             System.out.println("1: Create Account");
             System.out.println("2: Check Account");
             System.out.println("3: Take Action");
             System.out.println("4: Exit");



        System.out.println("Please choose");
         Choice= Option.nextInt();  




    switch (Choice)  //used switch statement instead of If else because more effective
    {
    case 1:

        CreateAccount();
        break;   //breaks iteration




    case 2: 

        selectAccount();


        break;

    case 3:


        break;
    case 4:
        System.out.println("Bye"); 
        System.exit(0);
    default:
        System.out.println("Invalid Entry");
        break;


} 
}



catch (Exception e){
    System.out.println("Cant do that"); 
}
} while (true);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently you are not throwing any exception.

If you  want to throw an exception.
Please create default case and throw exception from it

Made default case as below

```
default:
    System.out.println("Invalid Entry");
    throw new Exception();
```

Comment: [`.nextInt()` from `Scanner` can throw plenty of exceptions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt--). And they are all unchecked to boot.